# Ruby on Rails Paperclip gem nested form проблема с сохранением

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Доброго дня. Делаю небольшой проект, столкнулся с проблемой не сохранения фотографий.

Мои модели:

```
class Arendakvartir < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :attachments, dependent: :destroy
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
 validates_associated :attachments

end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base


  belongs_to :arendakvartir

  has_attached_file :image,
                    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:id/:filename",
                    :url  => "/images/:id/:filename",
                    styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
 validates_attachment :image, presence: true
  validates_attachment_size :image, :less_than => 5.megabytes

end
```

Контроллер:

```
class ArendakvartirsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @arenda = Arendakvartir.new()
  end

  def show

  end


  def create
 # binding.pry
    @arenda = Arendakvartir.new()
    @arenda.attachments.build()

    if @arenda.save(arenda_params)
      respond_to do |format|
          flash[:positive] = "Объект сохранен успешно"
          format.html { redirect_to new_arendakvartir_path }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
          flash[:negative] =  "Объект не был сохранен успешно"
          format.html { render action: 'new'}
     end
   end
end
  private

  def arenda_params

    params.require(:arendakvartir).permit(:attachments_attributes =[:image]

    )
  end


end
```

Форма с предложением:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@arenda, :html =>  { :class => "ui form", :id => "create_new_arenda", :multipart => true }) do |t| %>

        <%= render 'shared/errors', :obj => @arenda  %>

          <%= t.fields_for :attachments do |a| %>
              <%= a.file_field :image, :name => 'arendakvartir[attachments_attributes][][image]' %>
          <% end %>



<%= submit_tag("Добавить объект", :class => "ui huge olive button") %>

<% end %>
```

В конечном итоге получаю ошибку валидации модели Attachment

В форме присутствуют ошибки:

Attachments image can't be blank
Attachments is invalid

Подскажите где же я тут не прав. Мой gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'pg'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'paperclip', '~> 4.3'
#gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.15', '>= 2.15.4'
#Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem "wysiwyg-rails"
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem "nested_form"
gem 'semantic-ui-sass', github: 'doabit/semantic-ui-sass'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'pry'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Хэшмап с атрибутами есть смысл передавать в следующие методы **модели**:

- `new` (`build` для ассоциации)
- `create`
- `assign_attributes`
- `update_attributes` (+ алиас `update`)

...но не в `save`, который отвечает исключительно за запись текущего состояния объекта в БД.